# Eureka - how to pass values to elements in custom row

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I my swift projects using Eureka forms and I have a customer row:

This is my Xib:

[image]

This is my class:

```
public class CustomServiceCell : Cell<Bool>, CellType{

    @IBOutlet weak var btnDelete: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!


    public override func setup() {
        //height = { 60 }
        //lblTitle.text = row.title
        super.setup()
        selectionStyle = .None
        //btnDelete.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onDelete), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    }

    @IBAction func onDelete(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Delete Button tapped")
        row.value = true

    }

    public override func update() {
        super.update()

    }
}
```

And this is how I add it to my form:

```
<<< CustomServiceRow();
```

I would like to know how can I pass values to set the name of the text of my button and the text of my label.

Any clue?

Comment: What have you found on Eureka's documentation?

Comment: There is no information about doing this.

Comment: There is in the first page of [Eureka's readme](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#using-the-callbacks)

Comment: Thats for rows that comes with the framework but my question is related to a customer row that has custom elements such buttons and labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Eureka's readme](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#using-the-callbacks) in Github:

```
let row  = SwitchRow("SwitchRow") { row in      // initializer
                        row.title = "The title"
                    }.onChange { row in
                        row.title = (row.value ?? false) ? "The title expands when on" : "The title"
                        row.updateCell()
                    }.cellSetup { cell, row in
                        cell.backgroundColor = .lightGrayColor()
                    }.cellUpdate { cell, row in
                        cell.textLabel?.font = .italicSystemFontOfSize(18.0)
                }
```

Comment: Let me try it... with cellSetup. Give me asec

Comment: Amazing... it was always in my sight but didnt see it. Appreciate so much.